Movie where faces are on a mold
I saw this in the late 1970s or early 1980s. The dialogue was definitely American English. I'm not sure if it could have been a foreign film that was dubbed, but it definitely was not subtitled.
I remember seeing this movie when I was very young. The scene I remember was either at night or in black and white.
Basically, there is a female co-ed student running around and there is a guy after her and her friends. He chases after her at various points. But what I remember most is that after he gets each of her friends, that friend's face is placed on a mold or something held on like a hand-held mirror. So, when the killer holds up the face, the student is seeing her friend's face and knows that they are dead.
For a long time, I thought it was Eyes Without a Face, but after watching it recently, I realized that it is not the same film — just a similar premise. I have also watched The Awful Dr. Orloff and Mill of the Stone Women, and it is neither of those either. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Hope we can help. Any chance you can give us more details? Not necessarily even plot-related - e.g. saying when you saw it would be super helpful. (i.e. "When you were very young" could be any time from, say... the '50s/'60s to the early 2000s. So when is "when you were young"?) And do you know what language it was it/what country you think it might have been from? And/or what country you watched it in? Thanks!

(P.S. You can add any of this info to your question by clicking the "edit" button below the post.)

Thanks. I added the time period in which I saw the film.

Do you mean co-ed, as in a student?

Yes, as in college student. I vaguely remember there being a loose reference to them going to a university.
